# My employer filed a report against me and refuses to pay me

Tags: criminal-law

I was working at a an old Mansion turned into a hotel and I had the keys for it so one night I went in after hours without the owners permission and brought some friends. We caused absolutely no damages. My boss found out and filed a police report but by the time he told me about it he said he had taken it back. That happened in August. In October I quit and when I tried to get my paycheck he told me I had an arrest warrant that he thought he took care of but apparently not. Every conversation I tried to have about getting my check he turned into my arrest warrant. Apparently he’s fixed it now and I no longer have an arrest warrant but now he’s saying I owe him $225 for the lawyers. The hours he owes me are 22 hours and I got paid 10$ an hour. I called him asking to get paid and he threatened to just put the arrest warrant back on because I supposedly owe him. I was considering going to the department of labor but I don’t know. If I do can he just put the arrest warrant back on me? If he does will I really go to jail for that? Should I just let it go? He’s also very involved with politicians here in New Orleans so he’s got friends in high places. I just don’t know the laws that could help or hurt me.

Comment: Check out https://slls.org/ for free legal aid.

Comment: Hello!  Welcome to Law.SE.  Please read our [tour page](https://law.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: I assume you know it's illegal for him to withhold wages, you're only asking about the possibility of future arrest and prosecution. But the boss doesn't arrest or prosecute, that's up the the government. He may be able to persuade the police and prosecutor to arrest and prosecute you, and from what you tell us, yes, they can do that. You don't give enough details about the earlier arrest warrant for us to be able to comment on that aspect.

Answer (score 1):

You worked 22 hours for $10 an hour, he owes you $220, simple as that. He has to pay. No choice at all. So *do* go to the department of labour.

Next, assuming that you have some fixed address, the police never had an arrest against you. If they had had a warrant, you would have been arrested. You were not arrested, so there never was a warrant. And if he had gone to the police with a complaint against you, then withdrawn his complaint, the police would be just laughing at him if he came back with the same complaint. They have frankly better things to do.

On the other hand, he is threatening you to avoid paying for your work. That is in itself sailing very, very close to the wind. So that is something that you surely mention when you go to the department of labour.

As far as his lawyer costs are concerned, what lawyer costs? If someone enters my house without permission, and I go to the police, I'll just make a statement to the police and sit back and relax. There is no need for a lawyer, so there is no need for you to pay for a lawyer. There is also no need for a lawyer if you withdraw a statement (unless the police accuses me of wasting police time, and then I might need a lawyer for myself, but that has nothing to do with you).

So I very much doubt that there was ever a lawyer who cost money. Even if there was a lawyer, that's his problem, not yours.

Other than that, don't bring your friends to a client's house in the future.

Comment: People go for months or years without being arrested.

Answer (score -5):

If you were indicted then the case was dismissed before a finding of merit you can be re-indicted. If it was dismissed with prejudice, you can not be re-indicted.

The standard to determine if the case should or should not be dismissed with prejudice is whether it has gone to trial.
https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/can-i-charged-again-even-the-case-dismissed-arraignment.html

The reason for that is that when you go to trial, the court, or jury, has made a decision on the matter and that should not be undone, unless there was something illegal that caused the ruling.

As for the money, if you cost the employer money, he is free to recoup that money. You are not really entitled to his money when you cost him money by breaking into his hotel. You were a contractor who technically caused him momentary damages, (legal fees) even if you did not damage the structure. 
https://employment-law.freeadvice.com/employment-law/employment-law/property-damage-by-independent-contractor-who-pays.htm

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100717/discussion-on-answer-by-putvi-my-employer-filed-a-report-against-me-and-refuses).